# How to determine whether EventWaitHandle.WaitOne was invoked in a secondary thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a main thread which spawns a secondary thread. This secondary thread is using the `EventWaitHandle.WaitOne` to wait after performing some particular operation.

Is there any way for the main thread to be signalled when the secondary thread goes to the wait state?

I tried using `System.Threading.ThreadState` property to determine whether the thread is in `WaitSleepJoin` state when the `WaitOne()`-method is called, but this approach does not seem to work as the thread always appears to be in `Running` state.

Comment: Why not use another waithandle?

Comment: you can you another event and signal it just before the wait of second thread

Answer (score 3):

You can use the second ManualResetEvent to signal main thread:

in the worker thread:

```
signalEWH.Set();

commonEWH.WaitOne();

signalEWM.Reset();
```

in the main thread

```
var isWaiting = signalEWH.WaitOne(0);
```

I have wrote the fololowing test app and it works fine to me

```
      class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var thr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SecondThread));
        thr.IsBackground = true;
        thr.Start();

        firstEvent.WaitOne();

        var isSleep = thr.ThreadState.HasFlag(ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin);
    }

    static ManualResetEvent firstEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    static ManualResetEvent secondEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    static void SecondThread()
    {
        firstEvent.Set();
        secondEvent.WaitOne();
        firstEvent.Reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it that System.Threading.ThreadState property does not work?